# Javascript or JQuery not understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, javascript-objects

I am very new to the front end programming and I sometimes do not get the meaning of the shortcuts of the javascript and jquery. I have some code template to work on and I do not understand clearly that how it is working which are as below.

Will you please help me to get through article to understand these definations which are in the js file.

Thank you in advance.

I have something like this. I just want to know that how it works! I am not getting the clear idea.

1

```
for (var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div"), t = 0; t < e.length; t++) 
    "fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class") && fishArray.push(e[t])
```

2.

```
"vertical" == layersMovement ? (balloonDiv.style.left = o + "px", robbyContainerDiv.style.left = n + "px") : "not moving 1" == layersMovement ||
"not moving 2" == layersMovement ? (robbyContainerDiv.style.left = n + pageVerticalPosition - (pageDiv.offsetHeight - containerDiv.offsetHeight - distanceBetweenRobbyAndBalloon) + "px",

balloonDiv.style.left = o + "px") : (balloonDiv.style.left = layerHorizontalArray[layerHorizontalArray.length - 1].offsetLeft + layerHorizontalArray[layerHorizontalArray.length - 1].offsetWidth - .5 * (containerDiv.offsetWidth + balloonDiv.offsetWidth) + "px",
robbyContainerDiv.style.left = "50%")
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can assist you

Comment: To be honest that code is very badly written and some of it is useless and/or makes no sense. We don't even know the goal of this code, how would we know what it's supposed to be doing or if it's even correct?

Comment: Have a close look at these pages : [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) and [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) ;)

Comment: It is correct and working properly. In the code they have used this kind of functions everywhere.. let me give you one function.

Comment: function setLayersMovement() {
    layersMovement = pageVerticalPosition * layerHorizontalSpeedArray[layerHorizontalSpeedArray.length - 1] <= layerHorizontalArray[layerHorizontalArray.length - 1].offsetWidth - containerDiv.offsetWidth ? 
 "horizontal" : pageVerticalPosition >= pageDiv.offsetHeight - containerDiv.offsetHeight - distanceBetweenRobbyAndBalloon && 
 pageVerticalPosition < pageDiv.offsetHeight - containerDiv.offsetHeight ? "not moving 1" : pageVerticalPosition >= pageDiv.offsetHeight - containerDiv.offsetHeight ? "not moving 2" : "vertical"
}

Comment: @khushboobasolanki Please add extra code as a comment. I'll give an example of why this code isn't good. The line `"fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class") && fishArray.push(e[t])` is doing a comparision between the string `fish` and the class of the current element in the iteration. Basically if they match it will go on to the other side of the `&& (and)` then push the element into the array. Although that's what it's doing, the way it's written makes it very unclear. Rather that doing something like `if( "fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class")) fishArray.push(e[t]))`, which is much clearer.

Comment: That and the code seems to have no comments either. I'm meaning the code isn't written in a way that is easily understandable, which is a *very* bad practice. Even if you knew JS decently well, it would take at least some time to go through it and figure out what the writer was doing. Also jQuery isn't being used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming it to cleaner code will help you understand:

```
for (var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div"), t = 0; t < e.length; t++) "fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class") && fishArray.push(e[t])
```

**cleanning the code:**

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

==> Defining e to hold all div elements

```
for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++)
```

==> Loop for each div element in e. The first section of for statement can be used to initialize variables. For example: `for (var a = 0, b = 2, c = 3; a < b; a++)` This is why the original code defined e inside the `for` statement.

```
"fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class") && fishArray.push(e[t])
```

==> a && b evaluates a and in case the evaluation result is true, b is performed. It is a shortcut for `if (a) { b; }`. In this statement, if the class attribute of the current div equals to 'fish', push the reference of the div to fishArray array.

In other words, the code can be written cleaner like this:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
    var currentDiv = e[t];
    if ("fish" == currentDiv.getAttribute("class")) {
        fishArray.push(e[t]);
    }
}
```

The second code:

```
"vertical" == layersMovement ? (balloonDiv.style.left = o + "px", robbyContainerDiv.style.left = n + "px") : "not moving 1" == layersMovement || "not moving 2" == layersMovement ? (robbyContainerDiv.style.left = n + pageVerticalPosition - (pageDiv.offsetHeight - containerDiv.offsetHeight - distanceBetweenRobbyAndBalloon) + "px", balloonDiv.style.left = o + "px") : (balloonDiv.style.left = layerHorizontalArray[layerHorizontalArray.length - 1].offsetLeft + layerHorizontalArray[layerHorizontalArray.length - 1].offsetWidth - .5 * (containerDiv.offsetWidth + balloonDiv.offsetWidth) + "px",
robbyContainerDiv.style.left = "50%")
```

**Explanation:**
The second code contains nested conditions.
The following: `a ? b : c` is equals to: `if (a) { b; } else { c; }`.
I can write `a, b, c;` in order to execute a, then b and then c ( `a; b; c;` ).
With those two rules, take that block of code and rewrite it so you could understand it.

BTW, I believe you are looking on [minified code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think it's minified code. Considering the whitespace and variable names.

Comment: "fish" == e[t].getAttribute("class") && fishArray.push(e[t]) what if i have || in between.??

Comment: a || b will execute b only if a is true. Otherwise b will not be executed.